# custom action rights

Tags: custom-actions

I have a sharepoint 2010 site with a library.

this library has three subfolders.

the system admin has full control over the whole library.

All users have read only rights to the whole library.

User A has additem rights to folder A
User B has additem rights to folder B
User C has additem rights to folder C

I have added a custom action button to the ribbon that looks for AddItem rights.

SysAdmin see the button for all folders.
Users A,B and C don't see it at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationType="ContentType"
RegistrationId="0x0120"
Rights="AddListItems">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Groups._children">
      <Group Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew"
             Sequence="55"
             Description="Custom New Group"
             Title="New"
             Command="EnableCustomGroup"
             Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible2">
        <Controls Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew.Controls">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew.NewDocument"
            Command="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew.NewDocCommand"
            LabelText="New Document"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="0" Image32by32Left="-64"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            Sequence="10"
            />
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling._children">
      <MaxSize
        Id="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling.CustomNew.MaxSize"
        Sequence="15"
        GroupId="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew"
        Size="LargeLarge"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="EnableCustomGroup"
      CommandAction="javascript:return true;"></CommandUIHandler>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="Ribbon.Documents.CustomNew.NewDocCommand"
      CommandAction="javascript:alert('New Document');">
    </CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I need users A,B and C to only see it in subfolders where they have AddItem Rights.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Could you post your custom action please ? Have you used List or ContentType registration? I think if you use List reegistration, that it will look for AddItem rights on the LIST (not on item). So you might need to register it on the Folder content type.

Comment: i have added the code above i will try the content type

Comment: uhm, I guess u forgot to paste part of the cosutom action?

Comment: i pasted it all but it doesn't show it all.

Comment: its there if i go to edit
I have changed it to use contenttype and folder and it still doesn't work

Comment: Have u tried giving the particular user AddListItem rights on the list, and check if one user (who has that right) CAN see the button? While the others still cant? I will check on my sharepoint tomorrow morning and Will let you know what i got out of it...